# Whenever I try to see the logs, it keeps saying, "Error displaying log lines. Please try again."

Tags: heroku

In Heroku CLI, Whenever I try to see the logs, it keeps saying

> Error displaying log lines. Please try again.

I tried "Heroku logs -t" or "Heroku logs -n 100" but it freezes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and finally solved it by installing the Papertrail addon inside the Heroku Dashboard. After I provisioned Papertrail the "heroku logs" command started working.